# Using find_if on map to find by value

Tags: c++, stl

I have a class which has a map. I need to find iterator in map by searching for a particualar value, instad of the key. Using a member function predicate IsValueFound, am trying this.

```
class A
{
public:
  void findVal();
private:
 int state;
 map<int, int> exmap;
 bool IsValueFound(pair<int key, int val> itr)
 {
   return state == itr.second;
 }
};

void A::findVal
{
  itr = find_if(exmap.begin, exmap.end, mem_fun1_ref(&A::IsValueFound));
}
```

Iam getting compilation errors. Iam not sure whats the syntax for these function adaptors. Please help.

EDIT: Sorry. Please neglect the compilation errors arising other than from finf_if stmt. I need to get find_if stmt corrected first. Also the code doesn't have boost :(

Comment: `exmap.begin` and `exmap.end` are member FUNCTIONS. You should write them `exmap.begin()` and `exmap.end()` to get the resulting iterators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit**: there's obviously an **error** in my answer, `mem_fun1_ref(&A::IsValueFound)` doesn't work as a predicate for `std::find_if`. I'm working on correcting that.

you forgot parenthesis with `exmap.begin` and `exmap.end`.
I think if you had read the compilation error report, it would have told seomthing about it.

I would write that this way:

```
typedef map<int, int>::const_iterator MyIterator
void A::findVal()
{
    const MyIterator itrBegin = exmap.begin();
    const MyIterator itrEnd = exmap.end();
    MyIterator itrFound = find_if( itrBegin ,
                                   itrEnd ,
                                   mem_fun1_ref(&A::IsValueFound));    
}
```

but I havent't tried `mem_fun1_ref(&A::IsValueFound)` to compile. and I'm not used to using `mem_fun1_ref`, I always redefine my own functor with their `operator()`.

Comment: You need to bind `this` to the functor you just generated with mem_fun1_ref()

Answer (score 4):

Its slightly easier to convert the object A into a functor:
But there were other problems with your code (see below):

```
#include <map>
#include <memory>
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

class A {
    public:
      void findVal();
    private:
      int state;
      map<int, int> exmap;

      // Changed the function IsValueFound() to operator()
      // This makes the whole object behave like a function.
      // Its a lot easier then getting member functions and binding
      // the this reference.
      bool operator()(map<int,int>::value_type const& itr) const
                    //         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                    //  std::pair<int,int> is not the type held in the map
                    //  so you are not going to bind against it using a pair.
      {
          return state == itr.second;
      }
};

void A::findVal()
{
    // You did not specify a type
    // for the iterator in your code.
    std::map<int,int>::iterator itr1 = find_if(exmap.begin(), exmap.end(), *this);
                                                   //   ^^^^^^       ^^^^^^
                                                   // begin() and end() are methods.

    // Just pass the `this` object as the the third parameter it will act as a function now.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to use Boost Bimap you can create a so-called functor, an object that overload the function call operator `()`. In this piece of code:

```
class A {
public:
bool findVal(int s);

private:
map<int, int> exmap;

struct IsValueFound {
    int state;
    IsValueFound(int _state) : state(_state) {};
    bool operator()(const pair<int, int>& itr) {
        return state == itr.second;
    }
};  

};

bool A::findVal(int x) {
    return (find_if(exmap.begin(), exmap.end(), A::IsValueFound(x)) != exmap.end());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As for the compilation errors, you're declaring your iterator wrong in IsValueFound's argument list, for one. It should be:

```
map<int, int>::iterator itr
```

Then in A::findVal itr is not declared at all.

Having said that, scanning a map for values is not a good idea if you need to do this often. You should consider some other internal representation for your data.

Answer (score 1):

`mem_fun_ref` takes your one argument function

`bool IsValueFound(pair<int, int> itr)`

and turns it into a two argument functor:

`bool functor(A& this, pair<int, int> itr)`.

where the reference used as the first parameter is used to generate the `this` pointer to call the member function `IsValueFound`.

<s>You probably don't want anything `mem_fun_ref` related here -- the binders will work just fine:</s>

`std::find_if(exmap.begin, exmap.end, std::bind2nd(std::equal_to<int>(), state));`

Just realized that won't work for a map iterator... I would probably just write an explicit loop at this point.

There are a few syntax errors you've got here too but @martona already touched on them so I won't beat a dead horse :)

Comment: mem_fun_ref(&A::IsValueFound) gives me error. /error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments/

Comment: @user: Did you read my answer? You have a two argument functor, not a one argument one.

Answer (score 0):

you actually use your map as a `bi-directional map`, so you may find boost's [Boost Multi-index Containers](http://live.boost.org/doc/libs/1_33_1/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html) useful. They have a specific example of implementing a bi-directional map.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [Boost Bimap](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html).

Comment: That's a horrible name. A first I though it said Bitmap.

Comment: @Martin York: I didn't choose the name. 8v)